# What is the rational behind elixir versions?

Tags: elixir, semantic-versioning

I'm new to elixir. I'd like to know how versions are organized and how do I know which version is more up to date? I have elixir version 1.2 in my machine, but I heard of versions 1.9 and 1.7, despite those seems to came before 1.2.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The current version of elixir is **1.12** (major version:1 , minor version:12). The version 1.2 is rather old and 1.9 and 1.7 all come AFTER 1.2

The versions (from old to new) are:

1.0,
1.1,
1.2,
1.3,
1.4,
1.5,
1.6,
1.7,
1.8,
1.9,
1.10,
1.11,
1.12

Please note that there are sub-versions (patch versions) in each version.
So 1.12.2 is newer than 1.12.1